# Can I use MCBrowserViewControllerDelegate with GameViewController class instead of ViewController class?

Tags: swift, scenekit, multipeer-connectivity

I don't think so. The error I receive states *Type 'GameViewController' does not conform to protocol 'MCBrowserViewDelegate'*  https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MultipeerConnectivity/Reference/MCBrowserViewController_class/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `GameViewController` is a subclass of `UIViewController`, you certainly can since `MCBrowserViewController` is a subclass of `UIViewController` as well.

The error you are receiving is saying that you are not *conforming to the delegate protocols required to use MCBrowserViewController*. This means that in order to use a MCBrowserViewController, you first need to add `MCBrowserViewDelegate` to your class declaration similar to the following.

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController, MCBrowserViewDelegate {
```

You will also want to set your `GameViewController` to be the delegate within `viewDidLoad` or wherever you create it.

```
// create the MCBrowserViewController
let browserViewController = MCBrowserViewController(...)     
browserViewController.delegate = self
self.presentViewController(browserViewController, animated: true, completion:nil)
```